# How to bind a SharePoint textfield to a dropdownlist?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I'm customizing a custom list form in xslt using SharePoint designer.  In my list, I have a textbox that represents a numerical value.

I would like to present this textbox to the user as a dropdown list with pre-defined values (1-7).  Unfortunately, I can't use a SPFieldChoice because it is evaluated as a string in my SharePoint Designer Workflow and there aren't any built-in conversions.

I'm hoping that I could simply define an asp DropDownList control and use the ddwrt:DataBind syntax, but the following isn't working.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlValue" runat="server" 
   __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i', 'ddlValue', 
                    'SelectedValue', 'OnSelectedIndexChanged', 'ID',
                     ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@MyField')}">
   <asp:ListItem value="1" selected="true">1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="7">7</asp:ListItem>    
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The selected value "1" does get saved with the item when it's created, so it is picking up the databinding.  However, if I select any other value, it still records "1".

Is the syntax wrong, or is there a better way?

What would you do?

Comment: @bryanbcook: Please tag with `sharepoint` as well as the others when asking questions. Some SharePoint-ers monitor this tag only so you will catch a wider audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my binding syntax is wrong.  Changing it to use the *TextChanged* event instead of *OnSelectedIndexChanged*.

The following appears to work:

```
 __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i', 'ddlValue',
                   'SelectedValue, 'TextChanged', 'ID'
                   ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID), '@MyField')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

workaround:
try a pre-selection parameter

```
<xsl:param name="Anrede" select="@Anrede"/>
```

and use it in

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" 
__designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'SelectedValue', 'TextChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string('')),'@Anrede')}" >
    <asp:ListItem value="{$Anrede}" selected="true"><xsl:value-of select="@Anrede"></xsl:value-of></asp:ListItem>                   
    <asp:ListItem value="">----</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="Herr">Herr</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="Frau">Frau</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```